Is it Thailand's *the person's name* or Thai *the person's name*?

...and significantly surpasses that of his nearest competitor, Thailand's Weeraphon Wichuma, who managed a maximum of 346 kg.

Which is correct, "Thailand's Weeraphon Wichuma" or "Thai Weeraphon Wichuma"?

You can use the country name with possessive, or the nationality, e.g. Norway's {person name} or "the Norwegian, {person  name}".  Note that with the nationality, you're forming an apposition, and there's a comma between the elements.   In reportage the definite article might often be dropped:  Norwegian {person name}

Thailand's x OR the Thai Weeraphon Wichuma. Not in the answers and not worth an answer I don't think.

Either are grammatically sound but have slightly different inference.
"Thailand" is the name of the country, so using the possessive of that noun "Thailand's Weeraphon Wichuma" infers that the competitor belongs to Thailand.
"Thai" as a noun means a person from Thailand. So "Thai Weeraphon Wichuma" is using that noun it as a descriptor for the person, like a label.
It seems more inkeeping with the context to use the former, because saying "Thailand's Weeraphon Wichuma" not only identifies them with their country but with their country's team. In sporting competitions, names of countries may refer directly to that country's team.

Although it's rare, there are some cases where a person may represent a country other than their own nationality. (Fairly common in the Eurovision Song Contest, for instance; and there are edge cases in sport, including people playing for a team matching a parent's nationality.) It's more common with e.g. city-based sports teams. In such cases you'd use a possessive not an adjective.

"Thai" seems more like an adjective.Thai is to Thailand as American is to America.

@Barmar for some countries, the adjective to describe something from that country and the noun for a citizen are the same - Thai is one such example. But that isn't true of all countries. The adjective for England is English but that isn't used as a singular noun - we'd have to say Englishman or Briton. It would be wrong to say "English John Smith" - and that's why I can say 'Thai' before a person's name is a noun descriptor.

@Barmar American is also a noun.

@Astralbee "It would be wrong to say 'English John Smith'" -- Would it? Seems as grammatical as saying "the tall John Smith".

@Jol I think you've missed an important part of the discussion. You've used the definite article. I'm not saying "The British John Smith" is wrong. I'm saying that, without the article, inserted as an alternative to the OP's text in question, is wrong. There are exceptions to using adjectives in front of a proper noun - such as "good old John", but notably that is when your audience knows the person and you're just complimenting them. If you know who Keir Starmer is then you know he's British and don't need to be told.

There are three syntactic possibilities here, all of which are different with at least some nationalities...

(1) Britain's Louis Martin
(2) Briton Louis Martin
(3) British Louis Martin

Without the possessive, Thai (like American) could reflect the syntax of either the noun usage (2) or adjective usage (3). But Thailand can only be used in the possessive form (1).
Which format to use is essentially a stylistic preference. But the possessive form is more appropriate in contexts where the subject somehow represents his country, whereas the noun and adjective forms (which often look/sound the same anyway) are more suitable if you're just providing further information about the subject.

Note that the possessive form (1) functions syntactically as a determiner, and we don't normally attach multiple determiners to a single noun, so (1) can't be preceded by the. But optionally a determiner can be included before (2) or (3).

Also note that I've covered all 3 possibilities for the general case above - but as pointed out, (2) and (3) both use the same form (Thai). The specific context is "national representatives", so only (1) (Thailand's) is likely to be used anyway. But the other two are both valid, and may be used in other contexts.

I have to say this answer is wrong - your example 3 is not a correct alternative. It would be a very specific and somewhat convoluted context where that could legitimately be used, and probably with the definite article before it. Thai is different because it is the same word as an adjective to describe something or someone from Thailand and a noun for a Thailand native.

Rubbish. Are you gonna tell me this sentence isn't grammatical? a key figure in the organization of the policing apparatus of the Greek state immediately after this battle was the British Charles Wickham, a veteran of the Second Boer War. It's less common, but perfectly valid.

Your quote has a definite article, just like I said.

You're just nitpicking. I said in my answer that the article could be included. And if you're seriously claiming that cited text would actually be ungrammatical without the, i can only repeat: Rubbish!

@FumbleFingers: You can't mix the zero determiner with an adjective like that. It is ungrammatical, because it looks as if "British" is being used as the determiner (a role that adjective cannot play).

@Kevin: You're mistakenly conflating "idiomatically less common" with "ungrammatical". But if you really object to me the British Charles Wickham above, I'm not prepared to spend any more time defending the valid syntax.  The distinction rarely applies anyway, since the vast majority of nationalities don't have different forms for (2) and (3) in my answer. Offhand, excluding gender-specific forms like Irishman, Frenchman,... the only other one I can think of is Denmark's, Dane, Danish.

@FumbleFingers: "The" is not the zero determiner. I object to "___ British Charles Wickham." If you are not prepared to justify your interpretation of English based on actual rules of grammar, then you should not proclaim it to be correct.

Surely the onus is on you to find "an actual rule of grammar" that requires an article in my cited example. It's not easy to find examples of what I freely admit is a relatively uncommon usage. But if your position had any justification, it should be easy for you to find whatever "rule" you think applies.

Think about why we use an article along with a person's proper name - for example "I can't believe you met the Taylor Swift". We do it to emphasise that it was 'the' famous person with that name that everybody knows as opposed to some namesake. The only reason you would put an adjective in front of someone's name is if they need further identification. Like saying "the actor Michael Jordan" so nobody confuses him with the basketball player Michael Jordan. If everybody knew who Charles Wickham was, they'd know he was British. But they don't, so he's the British Charles Wickham".

We would typically use a construction like “Thailand’s King Vajiralongkorn” for someone who represents the country, such as in its government or in an international competition.
For an ordinary person, we might say, “Churai from Thailand.”
The other alternative you give would normally be used with nouns rather than personal names. Some real examples: “Thai Prime Minister Paetongtarn Shinawatra arrives at a cabinet meeting in Bangkok, Thailand,” or “The Italian billionaire met Thai businessman Bee Taechaubol on Wednesday [....]” In both cases, you could also add the before “Thai.”
If the same demonym also functions as a noun, such as “a Thai” or “an Italian,” you can use it that way here, although this is less common. As Janus Bahs Jaquet reminded me, if there are separate demonyms for noun and adjective forms, you need to use the appropriate one.  There’s usually an article, but you can drop it for brevity.  However, the construction “*American George” is not very common. Prefer something like, “George, the American.”

I feel inclined to disagree with the last paragraph.  I'd find it completely normal to read a sentence like "American Carl Lewis won four gold medals at the 1984 Olympics".  Perhaps it's not common to see this in the United States, because American journalists might consider it unnecessary to state someone's nationality if they happen to be American.  Certainly outside the United States, this is both common and normal.

@DawoodibnKareem That’s an acceptable way to say it. It feels extremely terse to me, personally, like something I’d read in a headline or blurb with a strict word count.

@DawoodibnKareem It works for some countries, but not all; more specifically, it works for those countries where the adjective is also commonly used as a noun to refer to a person from that place. It’s perfectly common to describe someone as ‘an American’ or ‘an Italian’, but we don’t normally say ‘a French’ or ‘a Spanish’, and I would find “Spanish Rafael Nadal won gold at the 2008 Olympic” quite odd and unnatural. Thai is kind of on the fence here – it’s less jarring than Spanish, but not quite natural either.

@JanusBahsJacquet There are corresponding demonyms for other countries as well, they just aren't identical to the demographic adjective. In the case of French and Spanish the demonyms are respectively "A Frenchman" (I don't think I've ever seen "A Frenchwoman", but I would understand what was meant if I did) and "A Spaniard". "Spaniard Rafael Nadal won[...]" is perfectly natural.

@Hearth Yes, my point was precisely that the construction given in Dawood’s comment calls for a demonym, whereas the examples given in the answer (“used with nouns rather than personal names”) all have demographic adjectives. (I deliberately avoided Spaniard since it still feels like a slur to me, even though I know few people outside Spain, and not even everyone in Spain, think of it as such. I just don’t like demonyms formed as pejoratives.)

@JanusBahsJacquet Interesting. I’ve never heard “Spaniard” used as a pejorative.

@Davislor As a kid, I was taught in school that it was best avoided, and that stuck with me, so I tend to avoid it. A lot of people in Spain feel the same way, but most English speakers don’t. In most common words where the derivation from the base is transparent, the suffix -ard is pejorative: drunkard, bastard, druggard, dullard, dotard (though often not when the derivation is opaque, as in bollard < bole [=tree trunk], wizard < wise, buzzard), and since it’s completely transparent in Spaniard, it easily ends up ‘feeling’ pejorative.

@JanusBahsJacquet That’s ridiculous. There are a lot of words with positive connotations that end with the syllable -ard: forward, lifeguard, hoard  It’s not used in that many other demonyms, but there’s Savoyard. There’s no basis to avoid it in either etymology or usage.

@Davislor Nobody said anything about the syllable -ard; I am talking about the suffix -ard. Those are two very different things, and words like forward and guard are completely irrelevant here, in the same way that lily and rely are not adverbs just because they happen to end in -ly. Savoyard does have the same suffix etymologically, but it was borrowed wholesale from French and has a different stress pattern; synchronically it’s not the same suffix in English.

@JanusBahsJacquet Okay, but several personal names etymologically contain the same suffix in a positive sense, such as Richard. But thanks for informing readers that some people don’t like Spaniard. That’s useful to know. It’s very rarely-used anyway.

Yes, Richard is another example where the derivation is non-transparent and there’s no pejorative associations at all. (Incidentally, bastard of course doesn’t belong in the transparent group in my previous comment: that is a case where the derivation is opaque, but the meaning is still pejorative.)
